# How To achieve such EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make A One Character EditText 
[image]

Do I have to make multi EditText Or there is another Way

Comment: The best and easy solution is to use multiple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making Multi-EditText is the easiest method to achieve this. Please take my code as reference. It is one-number-EditText. And it will switch the focus to next editText after you entered a number for previous Edittext
XML:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/id2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id2"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/id3" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id3"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"
            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/id4" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id4"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1" />
```

JavaClass

```
e1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.id1);
e2 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.id2);
e3 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.id3);
e4 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.id4);

e1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int count) {
                    if (count == 1) {
                        e2.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            });

e2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int count) {
                    if (count == 1) {
                        e3.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            });

e3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int count) {
                    if (count == 1) {
                        e4.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            });
```